# Cannot satisfy dependency in STS4 org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 4.12.0

Tags: spring-tools-4

It is not possible to install org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 4.12.0 in eclipse 2021-09.

The only message in the logs is "no remedy found".

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Spring Tool Suite 4 4.12.0.202109130803 (org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 4.12.0.202109130803)
  Software currently installed: Equinox p2, Provisioning for IDEs. 2.4.1300.v20210830-0925 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.4.1300.v20210830-0925)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) 1.3.700.v20210726-0943 (org.eclipse.equinox.security 1.3.700.v20210726-0943)
    Equinox Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) 1.3.600.v20210126-1005 (org.eclipse.equinox.security 1.3.600.v20210126-1005)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2, headless functionalities 1.6.1100.v20210830-0925 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.6.1100.v20210830-0925)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.security [1.3.700.v20210726-0943,1.3.700.v20210726-0943]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2, Provisioning for IDEs. 2.4.1300.v20210830-0925 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.4.1300.v20210830-0925)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.6.1100.v20210830-0925,1.6.1100.v20210830-0925]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.20.0.v20210611-1600 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.20.0.v20210611-1600)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.security [1.3.600.v20210126-1005,1.3.600.v20210126-1005]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite 4 4.12.0.202109130803 (org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 4.12.0.202109130803)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.20.0.v20210611-1600,4.20.0.v20210611-1600]
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branding feature is nothing that you should install into an existing Eclipse installation. It provides the product branding for the Spring Tools 4 distribution and does not provide any functionality beyond that.

If you want to install the Spring Tools 4 into an existing Eclipse installation, you can:

- use the Eclipse Marketplace entry for Spring Tools 4
- or install from the p2 repository by selecting the features you want to instal manually (as described here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Installation#install-spring-tools-4-into-an-existing-eclipse-via-a-p2-repo)

Another way would be to download the ready-to-use distribution from https://spring.io/tools, which comes with the latest Eclipse release included and Spring Tools 4 pre-installed.